# View controller origin changes every time it's presented

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

**This is what my view controller should be:**

[image]

**This is what it is sometimes:**

[image]

I want to display a view controller in the circle, however, almost every time the view controller in the circle (`ResultViewController`) is presented, it's place is different, though its properties doesn't change at all. Here's my code:

```
func openCircle(withCenter center: CGPoint, dataSource: ([Items], Int, String)){
    self.addCircle(withCenter: center, dataSource: dataSource)
}

func addCircle(withCenter circleCenter: CGPoint, dataSource: ([Items], Int, String)) {

    let longerSide = fmax(view.frame.size.height, view.frame.size.width)
    let shorterSide = fmin(view.frame.size.height, view.frame.size.width)

    let circleRadius = longerSide / 2
    var resultViewOrigin = CGPoint()
    var resultViewSize = CGSize()

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

        let rectWidth = shorterSide / 2
        let rectHeight = sqrt(abs(circleRadius * circleRadius - rectWidth * rectWidth)) + view.frame.size.height - circleCenter.y
        resultViewSize = CGSize(width: rectWidth, height: rectHeight)
        resultViewOrigin = CGPoint(x: (view.frame.size.width - rectWidth) / 2, y: view.frame.size.height - rectHeight)

    } else {
        resultViewOrigin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        resultViewSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }

    let resultViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultVC") as! ResultViewController
    resultViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    resultViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    resultViewController.dataSource = dataSource
    resultViewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: resultViewOrigin, size: resultViewSize)

    transition.circle = UIView()
    transition.startingPoint = circleCenter
    transition.radius = circleRadius
    transition.circle.frame = circleFrame(radius: transition.radius, center: transition.startingPoint)

    present(resultViewController, animated: true)
}
```

It works well on the iPhone, not on the iPad, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you able to include a screenshot of the desired display? (from iPhone)

Comment: @Danoram sorry for the late response, please see the edit

Comment: Can you take better photos? I can't understand what's the problem. And possibly highlight them?

Comment: @Honey do you notice that in the second screen shot, a part of the text is not inside the circle? There's a view controller in the circle and it should be within the bounds of the circle

Comment: *however, almost every time the view controller in the circle (ResultViewController) is presented, it's place is different, though its properties doesn't change at all.* well that's a good way to find issue. Tell us how it differs on a **fixed set of properties**. Also my *hunch* is that your mistake is rooted in using **bounds** & **frame** instead of each other in the wrong place

Comment: @Honey so when I print out the `resultViewOrigin` on the iPad every time `ResultViewController` is presented, the value is the same, however as you can see in the photo clearly the origin is different

Comment: May be it can solve your problem. After setting the frame of your resultViewController you can set its view's center as         `resultViewController.view.center = self.view.center`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, it's actually a missing constraint on Regular-Regular size class caused this problem, I fixed it by adding a spacing to bottom layout guide to the part that used to get misplaced.

Thanks to everybody for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *container view*  instead of presenting the view controller. You can create them programmatically or in interface builder (see [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)).

Comment: I have animations attached to the presented view controller, container view isn't an optimal solution to me

Comment: The container view is a usual view. You can show or hide them with view animations. Why it's not optimal for you?

Comment: Not just animations, also a lot of data and connections, the migration from view controller to a container view is way too high

Comment: A container view contains a view with view controller.